# Laravel, issue with embedding image in job queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-queue

I have a strange issue with embedding image in job queue.
I am using WAMP for development.
Folder structure for my project is
**C:\wamp\MyProject**
& the public directory is at
**C:\wamp\www\app**

```
Mail::send('emails.mailtemplate_rule', ['body' => $data['body']], function ($message) use ($data) {
    $message->to($data['to']);
    $message->from($data['from'], $data['namefrom']);
    $message->subject($data['subject']);
});
```

```html
<img src="{{ $message->embed('assets/images/logo.png')}}" alt='MyProject' data-default="placeholder" data-max-width="300">
```

This is working fine when I run this but when I change the driver from 'sync' to 'database' and update the mail function as below:

```
Mail::queue('emails.mailtemplate_template', ['body' => $data['body']], function ($message) use ($data) {
    $message->to($data['to']);
    $message->from($data['from'], $data['namefrom']);
    $message->subject($data['subject']);
});
```

When I run the above, I can see the data entry in my jobs table.
but when I execute the command:  `php artisan queue:work`
It throws as exception which is

> [Error Exception]
>   fopen(assets/images/logo.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

If I remove the image it works as a charm.
Now I am wondering that why it is not able to find the image while without using job queue it can find the image & embed it into the mail.
It should work as desired.
Any help to this, will be appreciated.

Comment: it is permission issue.. i guess

Comment: Probably because your path is relative. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed('assets/images/logo.png')}}" alt='MyProject' data-default="placeholder" data-max-width="300">
```

to

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed(asset('images/logo.png'))}}" alt='MyProject' data-default="placeholder" data-max-width="300">
```

`asset()` is one of the helper class of laravel. [Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset)

it will work fine..

Comment: Worked well for me. Thanks

Comment: I have been working with laravel for over an year but still there are somethings I haven't seen so far. Thanks again @Jaimin

Comment: I guess asset() turns the relative path into an absolute one, right ? You can learn about failed to open stream problems here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory